ESP-IDF: Unit tests not detected for source files in main folder (not in components)
Similar to this question I am having problems with unit testing in ESP-IDF; it does not find my unit tests.
The only difference with the other question is, I don't have components I want to test, but I want to test source code files (.c/.h) that are in the main folder, so not in a separate component...
The problem:
I use the button Unit Test: Build and flash unit test app for testing in VS Code. It creates a folder "unity-app", builds and flashes fine, but it just does not find the unit tests that I created.
#### Executing one test by its name #####
-----------------------
0 Tests 0 Failures 0 Ignored
OK

How my code looks:
The file structure is like this:
my-project
  - build
  - components (empty)
  - main
    - include
    - test
      * CMakeLists.txt
      * test_myfile.c (the test file I want to run)
    * CMakeLists.txt
    * main.c
  - unity-app (created by VS Code)

Contents of test_myfile.c (test taken from example):
#include "unity.h"

static int testable_mean(const int* values, int count)
{
    if (count == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        sum += values[i];
    }
    return sum / count;
}

TEST_CASE("Mean of an empty array is zero", "[mean]")
{
    const int values[] = { 0 };
    TEST_ASSERT_EQUAL(0, testable_mean(values, 0));
}

Contents of "main/test/CmakeLists.txt":
idf_component_register(SRCS "test_myfile.c"
                       INCLUDE_DIRS "."
                       REQUIRES unity)

The "unity-app/CMakeLists.txt" file that VS Code generated looks like this:
# The following lines of boilerplate have to be in your project's
# CMakeLists in this exact order for cmake to work correctly
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
include($ENV{IDF_PATH}/tools/cmake/version.cmake)

# Add newly added components to one of these lines:
# 1. Add here if the component is compatible with IDF >= v4.3
set(EXTRA_COMPONENT_DIRS "../components")

set(TEST_COMPONENTS "my-project")

include($ENV{IDF_PATH}/tools/cmake/project.cmake)
project(example_test_app)

What I tried:
I tried adding ../main to it, among other things, but I can't manage to get it to work.
I also tried adding the proposed solution to the other question to the main CMakeLists.txt but without luck:
set(EXTRA_COMPONENT_DIRS "$ENV{IDF_PATH}/tools/unit-test-app/components" "main")

Is it maybe impossible to test source files that are in the main "component"..?
